# eliminate c++ template in compiling

Tags: c++, templates, compilation, boost-asio

I am reading `boost.asio` source code. It's hard to read, because there are a lot of Macros and Templates. So I am wondering if I can eliminate all the templates with a specific example with main method. So I can read the source code in a simple way.

I know there is a `-E` option in g++ to expand the macro to normal cpp code. But I don't know how can I expand a template in c++ code compiling. Can any one give me some tips?

Comment: Most compilers can't take templates and produce source with them "expanded"--and the few that I know of that can produce code that's not intended for human consumption, and is much less readable than the original source.

Comment: Template instantiation is not done by the preprocessor, so will be unaffectedd by `g++ -E`.   I short though, most compilers do not have an option to emit "expanded" (to use your wording) templates, since they output object code directly.  In other words, there is no intermediate step in instantiating templates that involves modified source code with "expanded" templates.  C++ compilers that emit source code (e.g. a C++ compiler that emits C code, which is then compiled as C) will emit code from templates that is much less readable than the original templates.

Comment: Even STL has said he wishes he had a tool to do template instantiation so he didn't have to do it in his head.